# Swift iOS realtime audio processing with microphone

Tags: ios, swift, real-time, core-audio

I am implementing a Goertzel algorithm in swift iOS. I found some code to tap microphone but I am not entirely sure how it works.

For Goertzel function I have written a function where data is the sample that needs to be provided

```
GoertzelAlgo(sampleRate:Float, targetFreq:Float, data:[Double]) -> Double
```

I want to call this GoertzelAlgo function for each sample filled with realtime microphone data but how does the installtapOnBus works I am not entirely sure? I am not sure if the code inside installTapOnBus is even getting executed.

```
    let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
    let sampleCount = 2048
    let bus = 0
    var samplesAsDoubles = Array(count: Int(sampleCount), repeatedValue: CDouble())
    let frameLength = UInt32(sampleCount) // This seems to be ignored when passed into the AudioTap, therefore reassign within block.
    inputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize:frameLength, format: inputNode.inputFormatForBus(bus), block: { (
        buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!,
        audioTime  : AVAudioTime!) in

        // Change incomming buffer size
        buffer.frameLength = UInt32(sampleCount)

        // Populate array with incomming audio samples
        for var i = 0; i < Int(buffer.frameLength); i++
        {
            samplesAsDoubles[i] = Double(buffer.floatChannelData.memory[i])

        }
        //Probably the Groeztel function needs to be called from somewhere here
    })
```

Comment: Did you start by looking at the documentation?  Is there a specific part of it you're unclear about?  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioNode_Class/index.html

Comment: I did take a look at the documentation and even the above code compiles but I am not understanding how the samplesAsDoubles will get populated each time. I need to trigger the Groetzel function as soon as samplesAsDoubles gets filled completely with microphone data. I am a newbie in iOS development

Comment: What about other related documentation that provides the overview and use examples?   Such as...  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html

Comment: And:  https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/index.html

Comment: When I was working on an app to read the microphone I went straight to audio units and this helped, but it is still challenging even if you're used to the paradigm. Audio processing is a challenge in general, and a specialization: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is to use lock-free FIFOs (or circular buffers) to communicate between the 2 or 3 needed threads (real-time input thread, analysis thread, and frame-rate display thread).  Your AVAudioEngine bus tap only implements the first of these two or three processes.

Put the data received in the asynchronous input block into a FIFO or circular buffer (there isn't time to do much else), and then check whether there is any data there in another thread.

You can't tell if "the code inside installTapOnBus is even getting executed" without checking on the buffer from another thread, for instance from a timer callback running in the UI main loop.

Comment: Any good examples of a circular buffer in swift 5.0?

Comment: A lock-free circular ring buffer is currently unsafe in pure Swift 5 on ARM systems.  I bridge from Swift to a small bit of C code to sequence the memory barriers.

Comment: Wouldn't you know it, I got it working? Maybe not for someone that needs it to be thread safe, but in my case I just manually created an array of Floats and appended my samples to them in a circular way, tracking the in and out index. I needed this because I wanted to run an FFT which required 1024 samples (but on some devices I didn't receive enough samples so I need to wait til the next loop). Im only using one thread, so this worked.